# Custom buttons in Android

Tags: android

The default buttons in Android have round edges and lots of padding due to which the background is visible around the edges when the button and background colors differ. I want to make my own custom buttons which have:

1. Square corners
2. No padding around edges
3. Sharp edges

Comment: Please post what you have done, there are lot of tutorials for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a button in Photosohop with sharp edges and square corners, save it as .PNG. Navigate to `/android-sdk/tools/draw9patch.bat` and convert .PNG into 9-patch image. Import into your project and set it as a button background. For more see [9-Patch on Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html).

Comment: Ok, I will give this method a go and then update the status here.Will this method work for both normal button and an image button?

Comment: Yes. With normal button you could also add text via Android XML layout. For `ImageButton` you can set it also as a background and `src` leave empty.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just set the background you want to the ButtonView.